# angular l10n not working well while build with --prod --aot

Tags: angular

i have a angular project and am using angular-l10n to support languages on my site.

now i try to build my project:

if i am using the regular build:

```
"ng build"
```

the translation works fine and all components get a translation.

but if i using this build:

```
ng build --prod --aot
```

something goes wrong and part of the components do not get a translation, and part of the components indeed receive.

the configuration of the l10n place in **app.module.ts** file. and it looked like this:

```
export class AppModule { 
constructor(public locale: LocaleService, public translation: TranslationService) {

    this.locale.addConfiguration()
        .addLanguages(['he', 'en',  'Рус', 'عر',])
        .setCookieExpiration(30)
        .defineLanguage('he');

    this.translation.addConfiguration()
        .addProvider('./assets/locale-');

        this.translation.init();

}
```

example of components code:
ts:

```
import { Language } from 'angular-l10n';
export class RegestritionLogInComponent implements AfterViewInit {

@Language() lang: string;
```

html:

```
<a href="#"> {{'reg'| translate:lang }}</a>
```

anybody know why?

thanks!

Comment: where you are putting i10.config in a file or in app.module.ts?

Comment: i am update  the question. Thank you for your attention

Comment: Can you include a code example of a component you are using?

Comment: update the question. thanks!

Comment: the problem solved, it's fixed while i update the angular-l10n to ^4.1.5.   the old version not was compatible with my angular version (^5.2.0). thanks a lot!